# NHibernate, Antlr y Antlr3 Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, nhibernate

Tengo la siguiente situación:

1. Tengo NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 que requiere sí o sí Antlr 3.1.1
2. Hice una optimización de toda la aplicación web haciendo uso de ténicas de minificación y bundling con WebGrase que utiliza Antlr (>= 3.4.1.9004) El rendimiento aumentó hasta en un 38.8%. Para quienes deseen aprender, aquí les dejo un par de enlances: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification y https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification
3. Tengo ambas Dlls de Antlr en paralelo.
4. Al acceder a un controlador que utiliza **NHibernate** me lanza la siguiente excepción:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in
>   NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.1.0.39271, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=3a9cab8f8d22bfb7' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

*Este error sucede porque está referenciando a la librería nueva de **ANTLR** y lo que necesito es viajar en el tiempo y hacer uso de la librería antigua.*

5. He hecho los binding redirects en el `web.config` sin éxito hasta el momento.

Datos:

```
 <Reference Include="antlr.runtime, Version=2.7.7.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d7701e059243744f">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\Dependencies\Antlr.3.1.1\lib\antlr.runtime.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.4.1.9004, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Utility, Version=0.1.0.39272, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3a9cab8f8d22bfb7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\Dependencies\Antlr.3.1.1\lib\Antlr3.Utility.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\Dependencies\NHibernate.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Algunos de bindings que intenté fueron:

Usando el token de NHibernate:

```
 <dependentAssembly>        
        <assemblyIdentity name="antlr.runtime" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" Culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.0.39271" newVersion="3.4.1.9004" />
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>        
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" Culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.0.39271" newVersion="3.4.1.9004" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Usando el token de Antlr (y viajando en el tiempo):

```
<dependentAssembly>        
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="d7701e059243744f" Culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.4.1.9004" newVersion="3.1.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Seguiré buscando solución mientras tanto, al encontrarla la comparto :D

Comment: Hola @fredyfx, intenta activar el log de carga de ensamblados como dice [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1527249/1724791) a ver si así ver mas información del error. También podrás ver informacion sobre las redirecciones de versiones que se están aplicando

Comment: Otra cosa que también podrías hacer es capturar el evento [AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx), ahí podrías incluso pasarle la versión que tu quieras del ensamblado

Comment: Y asegurate que en los directorios de búsqueda solo tienen las ultima version del ensamblado, creo que una vez que se carga una version en el AppDomain, ya no se cargan más versiones. No se, igual el problema es que tienes varios contextos de carga y se esta haciendo un lio, igual [este artículo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782(v=vs.110).aspx) te ayuda

Comment: gracias bro :D estaré probando a ver qué sale :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al editar el archivo del proyecto (.csproj), se mostraba:

```
 <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.4.1.9004, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Antes del uso de WebGrease y la optimización, estaba así:

```
 <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
      <HintPath>..\Dependencies\Antlr.3.1.1\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

Hice un viaje al pasado. Estuve modificando el archivo **.csproj** lo he devuelto tal y como estaba antes, sólo esa librería que fue agregada y modificada, sin especificar version, ni culture, ni PublicKeyToken ni processorArchitecture.

Si se preguntan si dejó de funcionar WebGrease y las optimizaciones, pues todo funciona como si nada.

Le agradezco mucho a mi buen amigo [rsciriano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/602/rsciriano) por las ideas en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54129/822), he aprendido nuevo material y nuevas técnicas ninja para ver y analizar ensamblados :D

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema es que te falta configurar el redirecionamiento de versiones del ensamblado `Antlr3.Runtime`

La redirección que tendrías que configurar es:

```
<dependentAssembly>        
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="3a9cab8f8d22bfb7" Culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.0.39271" newVersion="3.4.1.9004" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Es posible que la redirección que he puesto no funcione porque el **publicKeyToken** de la versión antigua de `Antlr3.Runtime´ es distinta a la de la nueva versión.

Por lo que parece, coincide con el **publicKeyToken** de NHibernate, así que será una compilación que han hecho los propios de **NHibernate**. Otra cosa que podrías intentar sería añadir ese ensamblado como referencia (cambiando en nombre de archivo)

Si habilitas el log de carga de ensamblados como comentan en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527249/1724791) de S.O. en inglés, podrás tener mas información de como se están cargando los ensamblados y que configuraciones de redirección se están aplicando.

> Es importante que cuando termines, deshabilites este log porque afecta **muy negativamente al rendimiento de .NET**

Comment: gracias por el apoyo, estoy en ello :D